# Which tasks in "Scheduled Tasks" (gnome-schedule) use anacron versus cron?

Tags: cron, scheduled, anacron

I am trying to run a command once a day, but my machine is not always on. `anacron` says it's meant for such purposes, but I prefer to use the Gnome Scheduled Tasks GUI program.

If I schedule a task to run every day using the "New" recurrent task via **Scheduled Tasks** (`gnome-schedule`), will the task be issued via `cron` or `anacron`?

That is, if the computer is off for a few days and I restart it, will the daily task run just once for that new day it starts and then daily thereafter (i.e. like anacron?).

It's not clear to me how `cron` and `anacron` are used by Gnome Schedule Tasks. And do I really need to care which is used, so long as I go through this GUI?